# Confused About Debugger Inconsistency With [NSBundle mainBundle]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

It sure seems like the Xcode debugger has been playing a dirty trick on me for the last couple hours.

I was working with this code which has--in hindsight--a pretty obvious bug, but it wasn't obvious at the time:

```
- (UIImage*)loadBundleImage:(NSString*)imageName {   
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* path = [bundle bundlePath];
    path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/%@", path, imageName];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

I was using the debugger to step through the code, and it kept saying that bundle was nil after the [NSBundle mainBundle] call. This led me to search high and low for why that could possibly be and to try to fix **that** problem.

Ultimately, I found the actual bug (which was that I was appending the path twice), so I decided to do some experimenting... obviously, bundle **wasn't** nil, so why was the debugger saying it was? When stepping through **this** code, the debugger correctly shows the value of bundle after the mainBundle call:

```
- (UIImage*)loadBundleImage:(NSString*)imageName {   
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if (bundle == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil bundle");
    }
    NSString* path = [bundle bundlePath];
    path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",imageName];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

So, what gives here? Is it a bug with the debugger? My only wild guess is that the compiler is optimizing the consecutive calls to mainBundle and bundlePath into some sort of atomic-ish operation, so the debugger doesn't get to "see" what happened... but that when I broke those two calls up with the if-block... that forced the compiler to deal with them separately?!

Can anyone shed some light on this? Am I as crazy as I feel? Please tell me I'm wrong and that I can go back to trusting the debugger.

Thanks, sorry for the mini-rant, there.

Comment: hi you could be right about the optimizing. This is a debug build, right? What do you have set for your target's GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL?

Comment: You should change your comment to an answer so I can give you credit for it. Sure enough, I had Release checked instead of Debug (no idea why--probably just me fooling around and forgetting to put things back). The debugger is able to debug the problem code correctly now. I'm definitely learning this iPhone stuff the hard way.  Thanks!!

Comment: To construct paths, you should use -stringByAppendingPathComponent: rather than constructing the path manually using -stringWithFormat:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have already resolved the issue, but in the newest XCode build the debugger console should say "variable X has been optimized away" when you try to print it in a release build.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, just so I don't get dinged for not accepting answers. (jib's comment above is the actual answer... but comments can't be accepted as answers.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using stringByAppendingPathComponent: to build your path, not tagging on slashed characters. I have a standard category on UIImage that gets images from the Resources folder:

```
+(UIImage*)imageFromResourceFileNamed:(NSString*)name;
{
if(!name) return nil;
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
return [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
```

}

Use it like this:

```
UIImage *prettyImage = [UIImage imageFromResourceFileNamed:@"flower.png"];
```